# URL Re writing in IIS 7 ASP.NET

Tags: url-rewriting

i want to rewrite the url https://www.domain.com/app_ui/index.aspx to https://www.domain.com

how can i do this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't - move your index.aspx into your home directory (one up from the app_ui folder) and make it the default page. URL Rewriting is a bit of a sledgehammer for this simple problem.

Comment: Thank you Lachlan  But sorry, i didn't get you. can you please explain in details.